# RavenDB tenants load slowly

Tags: ravendb, multi-tenant

We are using RavenDB in a multi-tenant environment, users can create their own tenants and create their own applications there.

The problem however is that their databases idle from time to time (certainly in acceptance, but it happens in production too), and for some reason it takes more than 40 seconds to reload it. But we have only ~1000 docs and ~300 indexes (it's the blueprint for an application that should contain many more documents once it goes into production), and all indexes have a single `Map` and a `TransformResults`-clause.

Version : Both 2.0.2230 and 2.0.2261 (latest stable as of writing)

### General Stats

```
 ...
TransactionalStorageSize:26222592,
TransactionalStorageSizeHumaneSize:"25.01 MBytes",
IndexStorageSize:376263,
IndexStorageHumaneSize:"367.44 KBytes",
TotalDatabaseSize:26598855,
TotalDatabaseHumaneSize:"25.37 MBytes",
CountOfDocuments:975,
...
```

### DataBase Stats

```
CountOfIndexes:305,
InMemoryIndexingQueueSize:0,
ApproximateTaskCount:0,
CountOfDocuments:975,
StaleIndexes:[],
CurrentNumberOfItemsToIndexInSingleBatch:256,
CurrentNumberOfItemsToReduceInSingleBatch:128,
DatabaseTransactionVersionSizeInMB:0.02,
....
Errors:[],
....
```

### EDIT

The application we are talking about, has two components a designer and a runtime. In ravendb we store the design and the data created/used in the runtime. And each tenant is an application.

We have so many indexes, because for each query you create in the design mode, we create an index in ravendb.

Indexes have the form of: Map `from ... [from...|let...] [where ... ] select ...` with LoadDocument calls to load the required associated documents for the given lucene queries and a similar TransfromResults to shape the documents in the required form.

I will investigate if we can loosen the one-on-one coupling between the queries and the indexes.

Q: Is it better to have a few gigantic indexes, lets say one for each Entity on which we query, or to find some middleground?

Q: At the moment we don't allow in our design of the Entities to have 'complex' entities, ie nothing but value properties or references to other documents, could this have an influence if we have a little fewer and bigger documents, and thus have to do less calls to `LoadDocument(...)`?

Is there a reason this takes so long (40s)?
And any possible ways to mitigate this would be appreciated.

Comment: What version/build?  Also, the google group is a better place for this question since s.o. Is for coding questions.  ServerFault might be appropriate as well, but there's not much ravendb traction there.

Comment: I did post to the mailinglist, I tried first by mail and then directly in the google groups interface, but it doesn't show up... Any suggestions @MattJohnson ?

Comment: I'm not sure if they are moderating newcomers or not. If you just posted your first post, it may take a short time to be approved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I find a bit odd - your ratio of indexes to documents seems a bit high.  Why do you need so many indexes?  Can you merge them?

For example, if you have some map-only indexes on the same entity, such as:

```
// index 1
Map = customers => from customer in customers
                   select new
                   {
                       customer.FirstName
                   }

// index 2
Map = customers => from customer in customers
                   select new
                   {
                       customer.LastName
                   }
```

Clearly these could be in a single index:

```
Map = customers => from customer in customers
                   select new
                   {
                       customer.FirstName,
                       customer.LastName
                   }
```

It would reduce the stress of the server significantly if you could lower your index count.

Keep in mind that all indexes run against all documents.  In their translated map, you will see `docs.customer` - which is a shorthand for filtering on the `Raven-Entity-Type` metadata.

So if you have 1000 docs against 300 indexes, that's 300,000 times a map has to evaluate.  If you were to reduce the indexes to something more common - say 20 or so, that would perform much better.

Comment: I will add more information to my question. You have nevertheless given a good avenue of investigation.

Comment: I accepted yours, based on a further discussion on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/hXW0-7FtgEw). So, yes having 300+ indexes is a bad idea, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Answering 1 subquestion of this:

> Q: Is it better to have a few gigantic indexes, lets say one for each
>   Entity on which we query, or to find some middleground?

In normal circumstances you will never need more than 1 index per Entity type.

If you have dozens of entity types, you have likely fallen into the pit of applying RDBMS model design to nonrelational design. To put in perspective, we have a functionally rich system that is built on top of a total of 8 aggregate roots. With 2-3 supporting infrastructural entities.

We have a total of 17 indexes. 8 Map, 5 Multi-map and 5 map-reduce. As you can see we have a 1:1 ratio of Map:Aggregate Root indexes. With additional indexes for supporting aggregated searches and map/reduce for custom results.